# Swing Action Listener Called Multiple Times - Hyper Sensitive

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple action listener in a Swing app in Java Web Start (believe me it works great 99.99% of the time) that is getting called multiple times from the UI. Here is the scenario

- the action listener calls a server side (EJB) method which populates
  some tables in the database
- the server side can take a long time (upto 1 minute) to process the
  request
- the action listener is meant to call the back end just once
- in 99% of the cases (in production) the action listener works as
  expected
- there is 1% of cases where the back end method is called multiple
  times resulting in data corruption in the database
- tried to simulate with 2 UI's calling the back end with the same
  inputs, but couldn't replicate

I am thinking there could be 2 hypotheses

- the action listener is calling the back end method multiple times (possibly double clicks)
- the back end is too overloaded to maintain thread integrity

I have seen the multiple click action in the case of HTML buttons in a browser and handled it with javascript/jquery. Does Swing have a similar hyper sensitivity?

I would like to use Eclipse debugger to diagnose thread problems, but don't know how to simulate this scenario. Stopping one thread is tripping the whole thing from launching another thread.

In any event, the Swing application is hyper sensitive, if anything. It *does* the job of passing the payload to the DB, but it is doing multiple times in 1% of the cases. I can write some DB code to filter the data, but I prefer a fix in Swing, if that is the root cause.

I tried to recreate the bug scenario with Sikuli by sending multiple clicks
to the button but in vain. Can you suggest me a way to simulate this possible UI/Threading bug scenario so that I can apply relevant fix? This has to be feasible as Swing has been around for decades now and lots of legacy apps use Swing and EJB.

Your help will be gratefully acknowledged.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> the action listener calls a server side (EJB) method which populates some tables in the database

A long running task should not execute on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. So I would suggest that when you click your button you would:

1. disable the button to indicate it is processing the task
2. start a SwingWorker to update the database on a separate thread.
3. when the SwingWorker finishes executing you enable the button.

This would prevent the user from clicking the button twice while the task is running.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the `EDT` and on the `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Wow! that was a fast response. As mentioned it is legacy code that was written 20 years ago when Swing was the king of the hill. I can do what you say, but first I need a use case. I can't replicate the issue that is happening almost every day in production. Guess I can roll out a fix and watch the production data. But it is not efficient. I can't replicate the issue. That also  my problem. If you have any thoughts on how to go about simulating the odd-ball case, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I have updated the issue with Sikuli reference. Basically using Sikuli one can send clicks on the buttons. I chose to send double clicks and the Swing application just ignored it and processed it as a single click (possibly because the action listener is attached to mouse clicked event). So I hit a cul-de-sac. I need one reproducible use case so that I can demonstrate to the people above me and get their approval to fix it or for that matter test the fix to convince myself that it works. Thanks

Comment: Sikuli might be sending the double click too fast.  Try sending a click, waiting 5 seconds, and sending a second click.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I implemented your suggestion without luck. Sometimes the back end process returns very fast (based on the load). I have tried 50 ms to 5 s but could not reproduce. It is still a mystery to me how in production it happens almost daily.  I think it is based on the load. Somehow two threads are launched to update the same row in the DB. I have tried putting synchronized blocks around the DB related code. I am in a test-driven team. So if I can't reproduce, there is little chance that any code fixes will be allowed.. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I have simulated a 10 sec response from the back end by putting Thread.sleep to simulate a heavy load. The UI froze until the server responded. This is probably because the action performed is happening within Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) as @camickr said.